# Which ABI does compiler follows to compiles C code and how could I know from it (GCC for example)?

Tags: unix, gcc, x86-64, abi

1)Which ABI does compiler follows to compiles C code and how could I know from it (GCC for example)?

2)I learned that there are many ABI from the internet. I want to know in x86-64 Unix-like platform, do all the systems and compilers follow the same ABI? If they do, which ABI do they follow? Is it the System V ABI(https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf)?

I use `gcc -v --help` to look through the help manual. But none of them seem to show the ABI information.

Comment: If targeting Linux all the compilers for that platform conform to the x86-64 System V ABI that you referenced in your question

Comment: But how about others ABI like GNU ABI? What is the difference between them?

Comment: The x86-64 System V ABI is *THE* ABI for calling convention on Linux. The ABI covers bother the software calling convention and the system call calling convention for Linux system calls. Everything else is built on top of that.

Comment: You will also find that document you linked to discusses the C++ ABI that is used and they point to an external reference for that. Fortran's calling convention is also specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

For C, the compiler follows the ABI of the processor and OS which it is run on. The ABI doc you've found is what I expect to see for linux and Solaris.

For C++, as best I'm aware the majority of compilers use the GNU ABI.

Comment: So difference languages have their own ABI?

Comment: As best I am aware there are only two: C and C++. Pretty much every other language is built on top of one of these, so that's what it reduces to.

Comment: @Kevin_xie They're mostly all the same, but Go uses their own stack-args calling convention even on x86-64, for some crazy reason.  On 32-bit x86 Windows, there are multiple widely-used calling conventions and most compilers let you specify on a per-function basis with function attributes.   Anyway, C++ uses the same calling convention as C with rules for how C++ things map to C.  But there are some C++-specific things like struct layout for types with virtual member functions: the C++ ABI extends the C ABI with stuff like vtable layouts and stack-unwinding rules for exception handling.

Comment: AFAIK Go is unique in *not* building on top of the standard calling convention of whatever platform it's running on.